# How to run a query after establishing a db connection in a python script which uses call (rather than a dedicated library)?

Tags: python, command-line, sqlplus

I am trying to use the subprocess call in Python to open a sqlcl command line and run a basic query.

```
from subprocess import call
import time

#establish connection
call(["./bin/sql", "test/test@delphix-test.va2.test.com:1521:vd4"])
time.sleep(5)

#run query
query = "select * from test where test like '%test%;'"
call([query])
```

When I run the python script above, the connection is immediately established and I see the sql welcome banners in my terminal.  The query does not seem to run though, and I assume I am doing something wrong.  I know my query is correct as I can run that exact same query when manually connecting using sqlcl in the terminal.  The script for some reason does not call the query and I am not sure why.

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?  I suspect it might be because when sql establishes the connection the shell starts running a new process and 'call' won't work in that situation?

Comment: I don't know if your queries need to be terminated by `;`. If so, you would need to put that outside of the single-quotes.

Comment: What you are doing wrong is not using the correct tool for the job. Connectors exist for a reason.

Comment: @bernie> I suspect the program he's invoking is an interactive prompt anyway, so it will be confused being run this way. Might be worth looking if it has some flag for that but, seriously, doing that is really calling for trouble. What next, parse the output and hope it doesn't change when the interactive prompt is updated?

Comment: The reason I am going this route is because for some reason I am not able to establish connection to the Oracle database using sql.connector in Python.  For some reason the only way I can establish connection is via jdbc, and sql.connector does not have any integration with jdbc.  I would be thrilled if I could find another way to do this though.

Comment: Is there a way to process that with pipes.  For example, .echo "select user from dual;" | sql barry/oracle.

Comment: in fact, try this. http://kendriu.com/how-to-use-pipes-in-python-subprocesspopen-objects